# To compute total possible paths in a rectangular grid if steps to the right, up, or diagonally up are allowed

Tags: combinatorics

How should I answer this-"Compute the total number of possible paths from $(0,0)$ to $(7,9)$ if the steps R (to the right) and U (up) are allowed, along with the diagonal step $D:(x,y) \to (x +1,y+ 1)$."

Comment: How about counting, for each number $k$, how may paths there are with $k$ diagonal steps, and then adding up all these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem belongs to a family of numbers are known as the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number). You can arrive at this equation by solving the corresponding recurrence relation which represents the possible moves at each step:

$D_{m,n} = D_{m-1,n} + D_{m-1,n-1} + D_{m,n-1}$

For m = 7 and n = 9 the answer comes out to:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{min(7,9)} {7 \choose k} {9 \choose k} 2^k = 224143$$

Answer (score 1):

if you have $k$ diagonals you must be making $(9-k)$ up moves and $(7-k)$  right moves and you will be making $(16-k)$ moves in total

The number of ways you can do this is 
$$N(k) =\binom{16-k}k \binom {16-2k}{7-k}$$

To get your final answer, sum $N(k)$ from 0 to 7.

[Wolfram Alpha gives](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20k%3D0%20to%207%20%20%28%20%20%28%7B16-k%7D%20choose%20%20k%20%20%20%29*%20%20%28%7B16-2k%7D%20%20choose%20%7B%207-k%7D%29%20%20%20%29) 224143 for the sum, in agreement with the first answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I needed it to prepare for a test tomorrow.